# SSRS 2012 reportingservice2010 to render or show snapshot

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, snapshot

I can see, using the web service, how to run reports, create subscriptions, create snapshots, show the history of snapshots, but how can I render or show a snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the method `ReportExecutionService.LoadReport()` you can specify a parameter *HistoryID*, which can be either `null` or the ID of a report snapshot.

If you specify a report snapshot ID, then when you render the report it will render from the snapshot instead of running the report.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.loadreport(v=sql.110).aspx)